# How to detect text language of a Hindi string written in English?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, data-cleaning, data-processing

I have tried 'textcat' library and its giving this output.

```
x<-"My Name is Mohit"

y<-"Mera Naam Mohit Hai"

> textcat(x)

[1] "middle_frisian"

> textcat(y)

[1] "sanskrit"
```

Comment: Difficult as the example text is very short. cld2 and cld3 (Google's Compact Language Detector) give other results for y (Shona). You might want to see if googleLanguageR package with `gl_translate_detect` detects the correct language. [Online test](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=Mera%20Naam%20Mohit%20Hai) suggests that this should work.